# own feedback mailer code in joomla didn't send mail's

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I have such files:

mod_get_price.php:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Direct Access to this location is not allowed.');

require_once('helper.php');

JHTML::stylesheet('styles.css','modules/mod_get_price/css/');

$form_send = JRequest::getVar('form_send', 'notsend');

switch($form_send){

    case 'send':

        $your_name = JRequest::getVar('your_name', 'No name');
        $your_question = JRequest::getVar('your_question', 'No question');

        $send = ModLittleContactHelper::SendMail($your_name,
                  $your_question);

        if ( $send !== true ) {
            echo 'Error sending email: ' . $send->message;
        }

        require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_get_price', 'sendok_tmpl'));
        break;

    default:
        require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_get_price', 'default_tmpl'));
}

?>
```

helper.php:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Direct Access to this location is not allowed.');

class ModLittleContactHelper{
public function SendMail($your_name, $your_question){

    $config = JFactory::getConfig();
    $mail = JFactory::getMailer();
    $sender = array($config->get( 'config.mailfrom' ), $config->get( 'config.fromname' ));

    $mail->setSender($sender);

    $mail->setSubject('Сообщение с сайта');
    $mail->addRecipient('info@dmgroup.su');

    $body = "Вопрос с сайта<br/>";
    $body.= "-------------------------<br/>";
    $body.= "Пользователь: ".$your_name."<br/>";
    $body.= "Вопрос: ".$your_question."<br/>";

    $mail->setBody($body);
    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $send = $mail->Send();

    return $send;

  }
}
?>
```

and two templates: default_tmpl and sendok_tmpl

default_tmpl :

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Direct Access to this location is not allowed.');
?>
<div class="right_area">
    <h3>ЗАДАТЬ ВОПРОС</h1>

    <form action="index.php" method="post" id="sc_form">        

        <input name="your_question" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Ваш вопрос" required></input><br/>

        <input name="your_name" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Ваш e-mail" type="email" required/><br/>

        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Отправить" id="send-button" />

    </form>
</div>
```

and when i click on send button - nothing happens, also mailbox is empty.

What i do wrong, and how to write simple feedback module-plugin?

i use 3.1 joomla

module: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/mod_get_price.zip

with mail setting all is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Joomla 3+, in first place you should not be using JRequest, which is deprecated. Istead use:

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
// then use the available JInput methods, but the get() will do the basics

$input->get($name, $default=null, $filter= 'cmd');
// Parameters
// string   $name   Name of the value to get.
// mixed    $default    Default value to return if variable does not exist.
// string   $filter Filter to apply to the value
```

In your form, remove the action attribute.

```
<form method="post" id="sc_form">
<!-- form elements -->
</form>
```

Example of the JInput use:

You have:

```
$form_send = JRequest::getVar('form_send', 'notsend');
```

Just change:

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input; // only once on each method

// it will look as
$form_send = $input->get('form_send', 'notsend');
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I've edited my answer to give you an example of the JInput use.

Comment: and then so? : switch($form_send){

    case 'send':

        $your_name = $input->get('your_name', 'No name');
        $your_question = $input->get('your_question', 'No question');

Comment: didn't know why, but nothing happens, i still see form after submit, without sending_ok template, and nothing on mail... here is my plugin https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0.rar

Comment: so what do you think?

Comment: Fixed. Where can I send you the zip. Email something. BY the way... "I need this now" is some kind of thing you should avoid to type. We're here to help with no obligation and we also have our own personal and professional life.

Comment: sorry)) it's was just for attention

Comment: officegr2005@yandex.by

Comment: Ok, just posted here the code you need to change and it'll work. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it worked.

Comment: ok, thank you, also trouble is in  <input type="hidden" name="form_send" value="send" />

Comment: With the code I've posted and sent by email you'll have it all working.

Comment: and how in helper i could get what radiobutton i checked?

Comment: also, maybe you know why on mail service i see e-mail adress without @ ?

Comment: JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW this help's

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41326/discussion-between-mario-and-brabertaser1992)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that your module code is calling because-

1)You are using module so in order to call module you need to pass item id as well, if it's not set for all pages.

2)As per the code  `case 'send'` will never call.
So you can try this-

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Direct Access to this location is not allowed.');
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$Itemid= $jinput->get('Itemid', '', 'INT');
?>
<div class="right_area">
<h3>ЗАДАТЬ ВОПРОС</h1>
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="sc_form">  
    <input name="your_question" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Ваш вопрос" required></input><br/>    
    <input name="your_name" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Ваш e-mail" type="email" required/><br/>    
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Отправить" id="send-button" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Itemid" value="<?php echo $Itemid?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="form_send" value="send" />
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Strict Standards: Non-static method ModLittleContactHelper::SendMail() should not be called statically in /var/www/dmgroups/data/www/dmgroup.su/modules/mod_get_price/mod_get_price.php on line 16

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/dmgroups/data/www/dmgroup.su/modules/mod_get_price/mod_get_price.php on line 17

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that will work as you pretend:

helper.php

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Direct Access to this location is not allowed.');
/**
 * Class ModLittleContactHelper
 */
class ModLittleContactHelper
{
    /**
     * @param $your_name
     * @param $your_question
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function SendMail($your_name, $your_question)
    {
        jimport('joomla.mail.mail');

        // ensure that we have the security from the form token
        JSession::checkToken() or die('Invalid Token');

        $config = JFactory::getConfig();
        $mail   = JFactory::getMailer();
        $sender = array($config->get('config.mailfrom'), $config->get('config.fromname'));

        $mail->setSender($sender);

        $mail->setSubject('Сообщение с сайта');
        $mail->addRecipient('info@dmgroup.su');

        $body = "Вопрос с сайта<br/>";
        $body .= "-------------------------<br/>";
        $body .= "Пользователь: " . $your_name . "<br/>";
        $body .= "Вопрос: " . $your_question . "<br/>";

        $mail->setBody($body);
        $mail->IsHTML(true);

        $send = $mail->Send();

        return $send;
    }
}
?>
```

mod_get_rpice.php:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Direct Access to this location is not allowed.');

require_once('helper.php');

$input     = JFactory::getApplication()->input; // only once on each method
$form_send = $input->get('form_send', 'notsend');
$app       = JFactory::getApplication();

switch ($form_send)
{
    case 'send':

        $your_name     = $input->get('your_name', 'No name', 'string');
        $your_question = $input->get('your_question', 'No question');

        // $app->enqueueMessage("Mail sent", "success"); // Uncomment for debug
        $send = ModLittleContactHelper::SendMail($your_name, $your_question);

        if($send !== true)
        {
            echo 'Error sending email.';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Message successfully sent.';
        }

        require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_get_price', 'sendok_tmpl'));
        break;

    default:
        // $app->enqueueMessage("Mail Not sent", "error"); // Uncomment for debug
        require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_get_price', 'default_tmpl'));
}
?>
```

/tmpl/default.php

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Direct Access to this location is not allowed.');
?>
<div class="right_area">
<h1>ЗАДАТЬ ВОПРОС</h1>
<form method="post" id="sc_form">
    <label for="your_question">Ваш вопрос</label>
    <input id="your_question" name="your_question" placeholder="Ваш вопрос" required/><br/>

    <label for="your_name">Ваш e-mail</label>
    <input id="your_name" name="your_name" placeholder="Ваш e-mail" type="email" required/><br/>

    <input type="submit" name="form_send" class="btn btn-primary" value="send" id="send-button"/>
    <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token');?>
</form>
</div>
```